# $A$ is similar to $B$ if $A\oplus A$ is similar to $B\oplus B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Question:**

If the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0& A \end{pmatrix}$ is similar to $\begin{pmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{pmatrix}$

**show that:**

the matrix $A$ is similar the matrix $B$

My try:

since  the matrix diag $(A,A)$  is  similar  matrix diag $(B,B)$;

and  I want use this elementary divisor,But there is not in The plural number field

then I can't.Thank you someone help me,Thank you  very much!

Comment: Please clarify, what is diag(A,A)?  A block matrix?

Comment: Yes,@vadim123,It's block matrix,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses the notion of **elementary divisors** from the theory of canonical forms: see e.g. $\S$ 5 [of these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/invariant_subspaces.pdf) for the definition and properties.   I would be interested to know if there is a more elementary argument.

Use the fact that the elementary divisors of $\operatorname{diag}(A,B)$ are obtained by combining the elementary divisors of $A$ and $B$ (i.e., add the multiplicities) together with the fact that two matrices are similar if and only if they have the same elementary divisors (Theorem 7.2 of *loc. cit.*).

Comment: Hello,But my problem can't say is in the plural number field,so there maybe not have elementary divisors

Comment: @china math: I have no idea what "plural number field" means, but it sounds like you are concerned that elementary divisors are not defined over an arbitrary field of scalars.  They are.  See my notes, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Please bare with me. It would be nice if someone would help me write this in a simpler way. Anyways, here is my attempt.

Proof:
Let's write the rational canonical form of $A$ as $A_{RCF}$ and the RCF of $B$ as $B_{RCF}$.

We proceed by contradiction. Suppose that $A$ is not similar to $B$. Then $A$ and $B$ have a different rational canonical forms. That is there exists $h(x)$ such that $a:=$ number of $h(x)$'s in the list of elementary divisors of $A$ is not equal to $b:=$ number of $h(x)$'s in the list of elementary divisors of $B$.

Case 1.
WLOG, if $b=0$, then $h(x)$ is not an elementary divisor of $B$ but is an elementary divisor of $A$ since $a \neq b$. Since the rational canonical form of $A \oplus A$ is $A_{RCF} \oplus A_{RCF}$, then $h(x)$ is also an elementary divisor $A \oplus A$. However, $h(x)$ is not an elementary divisor of $B \oplus B$.

Case 2. Let's assume $a,b \neq 0$.
Then, $A_{RCF} = \bigoplus_a C(h(x)) \oplus A_1$ where $A_1 = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{k_1} C(f_{i}(x))$ for some $k_1$ and such that for all $i, f_i(x) \neq h(x)$. Also, $B_{RCF}= \bigoplus_b C(h(x)) \oplus A_2$ where $A_2 = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{k_2} C(g_{i}(x))$ for some $k_2$ and such that for all $i, g_i(x) \neq h(x)$. Hence, the RCF of $A \oplus A$ is $\bigoplus_{2a} C(h(x)) \oplus A_2$ where $A_2 = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{l_1} C(g_i(x))$ for some $l_1$ and such that for all $i, r_i(x) \neq h(x)$. And the RCF of $B \oplus B$ is $\bigoplus_{2b} C(h(x)) \oplus B_2$ where $B_2 = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{l_2} C(s_i(x))$ for some $1_2$ and such that for all $i, s_i(x) \neq h(x)$. Therefore, the number of $h(x)$'s in the list of elementary divisor s of $A \oplus A$ is $2a$ and the number of $h(x)$'s in the list of elementary divisor s of $B \oplus B$ is $2b$. Note that $2a \neq 2b$.

In both cases, we find a contradiction since $A \oplus A$ is similar to $B \oplus B$.

Thus, $A$ is similar to $B$.